# Column rename won't work for one specific column- R

Tags: r

I am working with large datasets that all have different numbers in front of common column names. I have created a function that changes all of the column names successfully except for one. See below  **"MOTH PD JB R YNG" = "MOTHR PAID JOB",**

```
vars_renamed <- function(.data){rename(.data, contains(c("R'S SEX" = "R'S SEX",
                      "HRS/W WRK SCHYR" = "HRS/W WRK SCHYR",
                      "R'S RACE" = "R'S RACE",
                      "FATHR EDUC LEVEL" = "FATHR EDUC LEVEL",
                      "MOTHR EDUC LEVEL" = "MOTHR EDUC LEVEL",
                      **"MOTH PD JB R YNG" = "MOTHR PAID JOB",**
                      "R'S HSHLD ALONE" = "R'S HSHLD ALONE",
                      "DALY CMNTY AFFRS" = "DALY CMNTY AFFRS",
                      "DALY ALONE LEISR" = "DALY ALONE LEISR",
                      "SCH ACTV-ATHLTCS" = "SCH ACTV-ATHLTCS",
                      "SCH ACTV-OTH ACT" = "SCH ACTV-OTH ACT",
                      "YRS PRF ARTS-OUT" = "YRS PRF ARTS-OUT",
                      "YRS VOCATNL CLUB" = "YRS VOCATNL CLUB",
                      "YRS BOYS/GRLS CL" = "YRS BOYS/GRLS CL",
                      "YRS PRT-TIME JOB" = "YRS PRT-TIME JOB",
                      "DALY ACTV SPORTS" = "DALY ACTV SPORTS",
                      "SCH ACTV-PBLCTNS" =  "SCH ACTV-PBLCTNS",
                      "SCH ATV-ACDMC CL" = "SCH ATV-ACDMC CL",
                      "YRS OTH CLB/ACTV" = "YRS OTH CLB/ACTV",
                      "YRS HOBBY CLUB" = "YRS HOBBY CLUB",
                      "YRS COMMNTY ORGZ" = "YRS COMMNTY ORGZ",
                      "DALY VIST W/FRDS" = "DALY VIST W/FRDS",
                      "SCH ACTV-PRF ART" = "SCH ACTV-PRF ART",
                      "SCH ATV-STDN GVT" = "SCH ATV-STDN GVT",
                      "YRS SPORTS-OUTSC" = "YRS SPORTS-OUTSC",
                      "YRS SCOUTING" = "YRS SCOUTING",
                      "YRS CHRCH YTH GR" = "YRS CHRCH YTH GR", all = TRUE )))}
```

All of the other columns change successfully except for the one. Can anyone help with why this may not be working? The function is messy but effective, I just cannot figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```r
vars_renamed <- function(nms) {
  vec <- c("R'S SEX" = "R'S SEX",
                    "HRS/W WRK SCHYR" = "HRS/W WRK SCHYR",
                    "R'S RACE" = "R'S RACE",
                    "FATHR EDUC LEVEL" = "FATHR EDUC LEVEL",
                    "MOTHR EDUC LEVEL" = "MOTHR EDUC LEVEL",
                    "MOTH PD JB R YNG" = "MOTHR PAID JOB",
                    "R'S HSHLD ALONE" = "R'S HSHLD ALONE",
                    "DALY CMNTY AFFRS" = "DALY CMNTY AFFRS",
                    "DALY ALONE LEISR" = "DALY ALONE LEISR",
                    "SCH ACTV-ATHLTCS" = "SCH ACTV-ATHLTCS",
                    "SCH ACTV-OTH ACT" = "SCH ACTV-OTH ACT",
                    "YRS PRF ARTS-OUT" = "YRS PRF ARTS-OUT",
                    "YRS VOCATNL CLUB" = "YRS VOCATNL CLUB",
                    "YRS BOYS/GRLS CL" = "YRS BOYS/GRLS CL",
                    "YRS PRT-TIME JOB" = "YRS PRT-TIME JOB",
                    "DALY ACTV SPORTS" = "DALY ACTV SPORTS",
                    "SCH ACTV-PBLCTNS" =  "SCH ACTV-PBLCTNS",
                    "SCH ATV-ACDMC CL" = "SCH ATV-ACDMC CL",
                    "YRS OTH CLB/ACTV" = "YRS OTH CLB/ACTV",
                    "YRS HOBBY CLUB" = "YRS HOBBY CLUB",
                    "YRS COMMNTY ORGZ" = "YRS COMMNTY ORGZ",
                    "DALY VIST W/FRDS" = "DALY VIST W/FRDS",
                    "SCH ACTV-PRF ART" = "SCH ACTV-PRF ART",
                    "SCH ATV-STDN GVT" = "SCH ATV-STDN GVT",
                    "YRS SPORTS-OUTSC" = "YRS SPORTS-OUTSC",
                    "YRS SCOUTING" = "YRS SCOUTING",
                    "YRS CHRCH YTH GR" = "YRS CHRCH YTH GR")
  ind <- which(outer(names(vec), nms, Vectorize(grepl)), arr.ind = TRUE)
  nms[ind[,2]] <- vec[ind[,1]]
  nms
}
```

Its use:

```r
data.frame("MOTH PD JB R YNG"=2, "R's HSHLD ALONE"=1, check.names=FALSE) %>%
  rename_with(.fn = vars_renamed)
#   MOTHR PAID JOB R's HSHLD ALONE
# 1              2               1
```

Comment: Will this work if I try and apply it to multiple datasets?

Comment: Ummm ....... try it and report back? If it finds no matches, it makes no changes. In fact, since all except one of the names you provided makes no change, this could be seriously reduced/simplified (i.e., a much shorter `vec`).

Comment: im getting this error: Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [product 216] do not match the length of object [3201768]

Comment: Okay, well, please edit your original question and provide reproducible data (since it works fine with my data as well as `mtcars`). The best way is likely to paste the output from `dput(head(x))` in a code block.